# How to create checkbox fields with the same name

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to create several checkbox buttons with the same name. The first checkbox should be placed on the first page, and the second one should be placed on the second page. When I pick up one of them, the second must be picked up too.
I use the PDFBox 2.0.29 version.
I try to do it the following way:

```
public void addCheckbox(String name) {
    PDField field = getField("checkbox1");
    boolean isOld = true;
    if (field == null) {
        isOld = false;
        field = new PDCheckbox(acroForm);
        field.setPartialName(name));
        acroForm.getFields().add(field);
    }
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
    widget.setPage(page);
    ...
    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
    widget.setAppearance(appearance);
    if (isOld) {
        List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = field.getWidgets();
        widgets.add(widget);
        ((PDTerminalField) field).setWidgets(widgets);
    }
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
}

public PDField getField(String name) {
    for (PDField item : acroForm.getFields()) {
        if (item.getFullyQualifiedName().equals(name)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but I don't see my checkboxes on the PDF document. Can anyone help me to add these ones?

Comment: Creating a checkbox is more complex, have a look at the `CreateCheckBox.java` code from the source code download.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I saw this code, but it doesn't explain how to add kids' widgets to this ```Checkbox``` field. If I try to create another widget and add it like shown in my example, I see only one checkbox, but in the pdf debugger I see two widgets.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr are you saying about this one? https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java

Comment: Yes, that one, or the one for 2.0 https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java?view=markup

Comment: The difference for you is that field != widget, so you'd have to create the widgets separately and set them to the field instead of `checkbox.getWidgets().get(0)`

Comment: See the CreateMultiWidgetsForm.java example on how to have several widgets for 1 annotation